# Is the Segmentation fault occurring at the last fclose in the for loop due to a memory-related issue?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

The code is producing a Segmentation fault error at the fclose statement. What's odd is that the error only occurs in the last iteration of the loop. It doesn't happen in the previous iterations. I've verified that the files exist at the specified paths, and the file object is not null. There don't seem to be any issues with the file paths themselves.

What's even more puzzling is that if I reduce the loop count to be less than the intended maximum, it works fine. For instance, if I use index=1 instead of 0 or subtract 1 from file_count, it works as expected.

I initially thought it might be due to too many files, but I even tried reducing the number of files in transfer_server_file_list, and the same error still occurs.

To summarize, the issue is that fclose is throwing an error in the last loop iteration I intended. I'm not sure what the problem could be. errno doesn't provide any information either.

Please let me know if you have any insights into the possible cause or if there's a way to diagnose the issue.

```
unsigned char *serialized_data_ptr = *serialized_data;
    transfer_header->data_type = 3;

    memcpy(serialized_data_ptr, transfer_header, sizeof(transfer_header_t));
    serialized_data_ptr += sizeof(transfer_header_t);

    memcpy(serialized_data_ptr, &file_count, sizeof(file_count));
    serialized_data_ptr += sizeof(file_count);

    unsigned long file_path_size = 0;
    unsigned long file_data_size = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < file_count; index++)
    {
        file_path_size = file_path_length_get(transfer_server_file_list[index]);
        file_data_size = file_length_get(transfer_server_file_list[index]);

        memcpy(serialized_data_ptr, &file_path_size, sizeof(file_path_size));
        serialized_data_ptr += sizeof(file_path_size);

        memcpy(serialized_data_ptr, &file_data_size, sizeof(file_data_size));
        serialized_data_ptr += sizeof(file_data_size);

        memcpy(serialized_data_ptr, transfer_server_file_list[index], file_path_size);
        serialized_data_ptr += file_path_size;

        FILE *file = NULL;
        file = file_open(transfer_server_file_list[index], "rb");

        fread(serialized_data_ptr, 1, file_data_size, file);

        serialized_data_ptr += file_data_size;

        fclose(file);
    }
```

I always encounter a Segmentation fault (core dumped) or double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped) error at the fclose statement in the last loop iteration.

Comment: Please consider posting a [mcve].  Posited code is not compile-able.

Comment: Running a build compiled with `-fsanitize=address` is usually great at diagnosing such problems

Comment: You're most likely overwriting some memory you shouldn't. Try to allocate blindly much more memory than needed for `serialized_data_ptr` and if the problem goes away you know how to fix it.

Comment: What exactly is `file_open`? Why have you invented some strange custom function?